# Работа с объектами в Java

Tags: java

Задача такая: написать класс изменяемой строки на яве. Есть список из элементов содержащих часть символов строки (в каждом по 16). Так вот по ходу решения у меня возникла проблема: изменения происходящие с объектом в методах не сохраняются.

```
class app{
        class myObject {
            char[] symbols; // набор симоволов строки
            int length; // длина сегмента строки
            myObject next; // ссылка на след. элемент списка

            myObject() { /*...*/ } // есть два конструктора, которые создают пустой объект и объект по строке
            private void split() { // добавляется один элемент
                myObject newItem = new myObject();
                newItem.next = this.next;
                this.next = newItem;
            }
            public void insert(String value, int position) {
                myObject current = this; // переменная для нахождения нужного элемента, после которого надо вставить новый элемент.
                /* Цикл нахождения элемента */
                current.split();
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            myObject val = new myObject("Hello world!");
            val.insert("test", 4);
            val.print();
        }
}
```

В итоге при инициализации объекта получается список из одного элемента. Далее после 4 символа надо вставить "test" и тогда должен получиться список из трех элементов, но не тут то было. Он остается прежним. Подскажите что делаю не так и как правильно работать с объектами в методах.

Comment: метод insert никак не использует входные параметры. Более того, делает странное - `myObject current = this;`

Comment: это я для краткости убрал весь не нужный код. суть в том что вставка нового элемента таким способом не сохраняется

Comment: Вы убрали слишком много кода. А то, что осталось - попахивает бредом.
Приведите весь код. Если он очень большой/содержит конфиденциальные данные - сделайте минимальный пример, который воспроизводит Вашу проблему. Ещё раз уточню - строка вида `myObject current = this;` намекает на ужасный код.

Comment: Навскидку, split() должен работать (в смысле вставлляет **пустой** элемент в список, после данного).

А вот все остальное неясно (кода нет).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LxhtFWTZ весь код, только прога еще не готова, так что кое-что может казаться не логичным

Comment: Начнем с того, что код на pastebin здорово отличается от кода в вопросе.

Насколько я понял insertPart2() просто включает новый список после элемента, содержащего позицию вставки, но никакого разделения этого элемента на 2 части я не увидел (ее действительно нет? или я невнимательный?).

--

Вообще, Вы бы лучше идею алгоритма изложили (обсудили), а то неясно что править - идею или реализацию.

По крайней мере просмотр каждый раз списка сначала (когда уже известен элемент в списке, который надо расщеплять) выглядит странным.

Comment: Бред какой-то... Без идеи (чего вы хотели этим реализовать) `ничо нипанятна`

Comment: @Barmaley, ну в принципе задумка автора понятна. Строка в середину которой можно добавлять символы, не переписывая все байты.

Comment: @avp ну а список то зачем?! Причем если длина строки больше 4-х то появляется связный список - жесть

Comment: Мы же не знаем, как преподаватель поставил задание.

Comment: Ну сделай `Vector` или `Array<Character>` и всего то делов. А то как будто в каменном веке с Си наперевес - жесть

Comment: @Barmaley, ну а что вместо списка? Про размер сегмента списка - согласен. (пришлось удалить и вставить - лимит комментариев (дурь!)).

Vector, ArrayList ... @Barmaley, очевидно ведь, что эти структуры не позволяют вставлять символы **в середину, не сдвигая** "хвост".

Кстати, попытки сделать что-то оптимальное в стиле Java (крайне неуклюже у автора), вот это жесть!

Answer (score 1):

[[@Виталий Леонов](/users/2337/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)](/users/2337/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)  обязательное условие чтобы было реализовано списком? 
Чего то меня смущают строки такого вида, например (данный из метода insertPart2):

```
while(after != current) {
    current = current.next;
}
```

Почему просто after.next не взять? 
Не называйте лучше методы method1, method2, method3 и т.д., сами потом не разберетесь.

Почему у вас должно быть 3 элемента, у вас же по 16 символов в каждом элементе "Hello world!" - 12 символов, "test" - 4 символа, при вставке должно выйти 16 символов, то есть один элемент.
Но вставляется у вас же опять как то странно.
В вашем примере в методе insertPart2 (по крайней мере если я правильно понял) происходит следующее

afterCurrent становится равным null (т.к. строка у вас всего один элемент и он будет current и current.next = null), дальше вы вставляее в current.next (следующий элемент) строку inserted
после inserted идет пустой элемент (берется по значению afterCurrent).
Соответственно у вас 2 элемента не полностью заполненные.

Ваш метод length() возвращает 16 (т.к. длина первого элемента у вас 12, длина второго элемента 4)

Ну вот и выводит все 16 символов из первой строки (включая 4 пустых символа), а до 2го элемента и не доходит

P.S.: напишите метод, который выводит каждый элемент и его длину (для проверки)

Comment: @rasmisha, не совсем так, как Вы описываете (естественно, смотреть надо "pastebin", а не текст в вопросе). Обратите внимание на main

    String value = "Hello world! Hello world!";

Получам начальное состояние - список из 2-х элементов, в первом 16 байт. Вставка заказана в позицию 8, т.е. в середину первого элемента списка.


Запрограммирован там сейчас бред, поэтому "test" вставляется новым элементом списка (2-м) длиной 4 (т.е. в позицию 16).

--

Еще раз призываю автора вопроса, описать идеи алгоритма, который он хочет сделать и обсуждать сначала их.

Comment: Ну код я смотрел в pastebin, кроме main (однако же вставка то все равно не верно происходит)

Comment: И я о том же (что неправильно). Или в программе куча ошибок, или алгоритм не доработан, или ...